# AngularJS dropdown value from form undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m trying to get the value from a dropdown when submitting a form in AngularJS but ends up with an undefined value. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ironhead/Td2NZ/280/
textfields works with $scope.nameoftextbox but how to get the name/value of a dropdown?

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
    <select name="test" ng-model="form.type" ng-options="option.name for option in typeOptions" ></select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $scope.submitForm = function (post) {
    alert($scope.test);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your model is `form.type` so `$scope.form.type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ng-model` directive, you bind a specific `$scope` property - `form.type` - to that select. This model's value changes when a user selects different options, according to how these  elements were created in the first place (with `ng-options` directive). So you only have to check the model's value, that's all! For example:

```
alert($scope.form.type.name);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpupanyn/).